# how to reduce time to load jsp page while using iframe tag in it?

Tags: html, jsp, jsp-tags

i have a jsp page in which i am populating another jsp page usingiframe, now problem here is when page(main page) is loaded after that the div where i am using iframe is loaded and unfortunately that page is taking time to load so it shows blank at that div for some time. so can any one tell me how my page(main page) should be loaded when iframe in it is loaded ?

```
<body>
        <p>welcome to stcak</p>
        <div id="pageId">
            <iframe src="innerPage.jsp" frameborder="0" width="1000" height="510"></iframe>
        <div>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how you can load your main page, then load your iframe.  If that is the case, then you can use some simple ajax. In this case I'm using jQuery to set the source for the iframe after the rest of the main page has been loaded.

This way your main page will load, once complete you can tell the iframe to load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#myIframe').attr('src','innerPage.jsp');
});
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>welcome to stack</p>
<div id="pageId">
    <iframe src="" id="myIframe" frameborder="1" width="1000" height="510"></iframe>
</div>
<p>content that should display prior to iframe load...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pages are loading but the concern is the page which i am trying to populate in main page is taking time to load and due to that there is lag (which is blank at that div), so just wanted to know is there any way to load main page only when the iframes are loaded..so that lagging part can be avoided or any other method through which i can acheive this ?

Comment: Ok, so the main page is the problem, not the iframe as the above solution will solve any iframe load problems. If you have other parts of your main page that are taking a long time to load, I would suggest loading them with ajax calls.

Comment: Try adding the following to load the part(s) of your page that are taking a long time to load. You will need to split those parts out of your main JSP page. This should go in the same area used to ajax load your innerPage.jsp $('#someDivWhereResultsShouldGo').load('timeConsumingPart.jsp');

Comment: inner page is using some scripts,while using ajax i need to add those scripts in main page because ajax dont take those scripts from there, which is creating conflicts due to other scripts(and this is the main reason of opting iframe otherwise i would have put code directly to main page).

Comment: Post more code showing your problem.  That may help get more responses.

Comment: Michael : i just want to load main page only if inner pages are loaded including all tags like iframe.

Comment: Please add more code to help explain further. If you simply want to delay the load of your main page until the iframe is loaded, then you will likely be looking at a javascript solution.  If you are going to access javascript files from different domains, then you may want to look out for Cross Domain Scripting issues as noted here: http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/iframe_talks_to_parent/  Without more code I cannot help you.

Comment: thanx michael for ur suggestion..i'll work upon it and let you know when done.